# Is it possible to start audio file in background mode

Tags: iphone, audio, background, geolocation

So I've paid some guys to make me an app i can't make my self.

It's a GPS based app.
The thing is, the user sets a destination with a radius at 20miles.
When the user enters the radius, i want the app to play an audio file. This works fine.

BUT, they say it can't be done, when the app is in background mode.
They can't start the audio file if the app is in background mode, they can only make a notification.

Can this be achieved some how ? 
To make the app play my audio file, when user enters the radius, when it is in background mode ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you consider using AVAudioSession? Following link might help you to achieve your goal. http://www.sagorin.org/ios-playing-audio-in-background-audio/

Comment: I'm very interested to have an update to this question. Runkeeper app is starting audio in background and it seems not using the blank sound trick...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was possible to do using @AnkitJain solution